# inserting period after every 3 chars in a string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this:

```
from __future__ import print_function

def f_comma(p_string):
   v_string = p_string
   if (type(v_string) == type(int()) or type(v_string) == type(long()) or  
       type(v_string) == type(float())):
      v_string = str(v_string)
   else:   
      l_string = list(v_string)
      for v_index in range(3, len(l_string), 4):
         l_string.insert(v_index, ',')
      v_result = ''.join(l_string)
   return (v_result)

print (f_comma('qwertyuiopaq'))
```

It seems that i can't figure it out why if i use a string longer than 11 chars the period stops inserting, but with only 11 chars it works fine. What i'm doing wrong in this piece?

Comment: Can you show an example of the output with it failing?

Comment: Your function does not work because you did not account for the extra commas you inserted earlier. For example, when the length of string is 100, you have to put 33 commas between your string, but the `range` function in Python2 does not account for that.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can insert a comma after every nth character like this:

```
>>> my_str = 'qwertyuiopaq'
>>> ','.join(my_str[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(my_str), 3))
'qwe,rty,uio,paq'
```

This should work for any arbitrary length of strings too.

Edit: Written as a function in a similar style to @mhawke's answer, with an option to change the grouping/characters.

```
>>> def f_comma(my_str, group=3, char=','):
...     my_str = str(my_str)
...     return char.join(my_str[i:i+group] for i in range(0, len(my_str), group))
... 
>>> f_comma('qwertyuiopaq')
'qwe,rty,uio,paq'
>>> f_comma('qwertyuiopaq', group=2)
'qw,er,ty,ui,op,aq'
>>> f_comma('qwertyuiopaq', group=2, char='.')
'qw.er.ty.ui.op.aq'
```

Comment: `f_comma(12345)` => `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`. OP's code shows an effort to support non-string arguments such as int, long and float.

Comment: @mhawke: good point, updated the function to convert using `str()`.

Comment: Being picky, but how about unicode strings, e.g. `f_comma(u'Café')`

Comment: Yeah, it's not clear if OP is concerned about unicode strings, but to your point, if it's an issue OP can easily use the `unicode()` function instead of `str()` like you showed in your answer.

Comment: The OP may not realise but should be concerned because calling `str()` on a unicode object can fail as I show. Anyway, I changed my answer :) I no longer convert to unicode; I only convert non-strings (e.g. int, float, list...) to a byte string. This enables the function to preserve the string type in its return value.

Comment: could this be one without a generator expression?

Comment: @udarH3: you could use a list comprehension rather than the generator expression, but there's probably no reason to (unless you have extremely long strings). `[my_str[i:i+group] for i in range(0, len(my_str), group)]`

Comment: *done, thanks for the answer, now i just need to understand how that expression evaluates

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative way to do it using slicing:

```
def f_comma(p_string, n=3):
    return ','.join(p_string[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(p_string), n))
```

I don't think that the type checking in your version is necessary. Your code checks for instances of an int, long or float and then converts any of these to a string. You can just convert to a string without checking the type:

```
def f_comma(p_string, n=3):
    p_string = str(p_string)
    return ','.join(p_string[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(p_string), n))

>>> f_comma('abcdefghijklmnop')
'abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,p'
>>> f_comma(1234567890)
'123,456,789,0'
>>> import math
>>> f_comma(math.pi)
'3.1,415,926,535,9'
```

Now this won't handle all unicode strings:

```
>>> f_comma(u'abcdefg\u3030\u3031\u3032\u3033')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in f_comma
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 7-10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here you can use `isinstance()` (preferable to `type() ==`) to aid conversion of non-string types:

```
def f_comma(p_string, n=3):
    if not isinstance(p_string, basestring):    # str or unicode
        p_string = str(p_string)                # convert only non-strings
    return ','.join(p_string[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(p_string), n))

>>> f_comma(u'abcdefg\u3030\u3031\u3032\u3033')    # returns unicode
u'abc,def,g\u3030\u3031,\u3032\u3033'
>>> f_comma('wowwowwowwow')                        # returns str
'wow,wow,wow,wow'
>>> f_comma(math.pi)                               # returns str
'3.1,415,926,535,9'
```

Also notice the use of a default argument to specify the segment length:

```
>>> f_comma('abcdefghijklmnop')
u'abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,p'
>>> f_comma('abcdefghijklmnop', 6)
u'abcdef,ghijkl,mnop'
```

Comment: @Nitzle beat you to it by a few seconds!

Comment: @LondonRob: yes... and it seems to make all the difference in the upvote count! :)

Comment: Sorry. I shouldn't have mentioned it. Still, @Nitzle needs the rep more than you do!

Answer (score 1):

Here's why it doesn't work. (Rather than solving your method which is a pretty inefficient one, as others have shown.)

When you `.insert()` something into your list, every element gets shifted forward a position to make room.

The indexes you calculated earlier with `range(3, len(l_string), 4)` are then no longer what you want them to be.

Comment: Nope, still does not work. Try `print (f_comma('qwertyuiopaqqwertyuiopaqqwertyuiopaqqwertyuiopaq'))`