# python selenium send key separated with spaces

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to send value `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until( EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='cardNumber']"))).send_keys("5546xxxxxxxxxxx2")`
I get only 4 digits (three from the beginning and the last one).
How can I send visa card number that separated every 4 digits with space?
Thanks

Comment: Add at least a picture of the input field and html code.

Answer (score 0):

[This question is roughly what you're looking for.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30919497/9044183)

```py
def split_by_space(p_string, n=4):
    '''inserts a space into a string every n characters'''
    return ' '.join(p_string[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(p_string), n))

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until( EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='cardNumber']"))).send_keys(split_by_space("5546xxxxxxxxxxx2"))
```

Comment: It's not working, note that html is auto add spaces. if I write the card number manually it add spaces automatically .