# How to print in next line after a specified set of characters in python?

Tags: python, mysql, newline

I am trying to take an entry from a mysql database but the entry is so long that it looks like really bad formatting when displaying it using python. So how do I start a newline after a specified number of characters? I am not using a for loop just an execute command from mysql

I couldn't really try anything because I cannot come up with an idea to circumvent this problem. I searched it up on stackoverflow and other forums but could not find an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a look at something like this (shown here with a print example)

```
def add_newline_each_n(s, n):
    return "\n".join(s[i : i + n] for i in range(0, len(s), n))


print(add_newline_each_n("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 2))
```

If you want to make a more general function, have a look at the selected answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30919275/inserting-period-after-every-3-chars-in-a-string).

EDIT: (formatted the code)